# Cordova geolocation navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition bad window access position

Tags: geolocation, location

I'm using Cordova and navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition to locate user when starting app.
But I have a bad message when app start : "/var/mobile/Applications/52E2F4B9-2066-4541-9696-86E18D5B16CB/City-Flash.app/www/index.html" Would Like To Use Your Current Location.
How can I change this message ? Why I don't have the app Name ?
If I go to my website, I have the right message and I'm using the same way.
See screenshot here : http://www.city-flash.com/public/problem.PNG

Any ideas ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing your app in Emulator. If Yes, You have to open Emulator Control in Eclipse and then send Longitude and Lattitude manually.
Worked for me...

Comment: No, i send the app on my iPhone to test and I have the same problem in production (in appstore)